# Grafana API Keys option not available

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

The API option under Administration is not available for me, I am using docker image (grafana/grafana) installed on a VM.
[Image showing the said option not being there][1]     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4eDm.png

Hello everyone!!

I am trying to learn grafana and I have one installed on my VM through Docker ("version": "10.1.2").

While exploring the app I got to learn that dashboards and data sources can be installed using API but I am not able to find the option API KEYS.

I watched a few videos on Internet to see how the said option is available but I wasn't able to find it.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use **[Service Accounts](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/service-accounts/)** in place of API Keys from Grafana v9.1 and newer.

Once you create a service account with the appropriate permissions, you can then create a **token** within the service account, and use that token where you would have used an API key.

---

The API keys [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/api-keys/) has a disclaimer of the above deprecation and points you to the same Service Accounts documentation.

You can also refer to [this blog post](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/08/24/new-in-grafana-9.1-service-accounts-are-now-ga/) for more information and a video introducing service accounts too.